# Crashlytics integration on Xcode 9.3 is not working?

Tags: xcode9.3, crashlytics-beta

I am having issue with integrating crashlytics on projects created using Xcode 9.3. Integrating through cocoapods, it is stuck on verification process forever, attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Try doing a build and run of your app after adding debug mode and see if that helps:

 // Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help!

Comment: Probably best to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io so the team can dig in more.